# Javascript Conditional Logic as function parameter

Tags: javascript

Can I have a Javascript code as below i.e. method attribute is based on the result of condition

```
self.renderViewContent(typeof partnerId !== "undefined" ? "myText1" : "myText2", view, {
    myAttr1: myModel.get("attr").toJSON()
});
```

Just to add, my first parameter is a string.

Comment: did it work or was throwing error?. why do you pass a boolean when you know the function expects string.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x02cw6uL/ suggests you can. Does it work your end?  It certainly makes the code less readable.  Why not just add a line above and use a variable?

Comment: you can't directly use typeof as a function argument

Comment: Do you actually encounter any problem here? Why do you ask?

Comment: @ChakravarthySM I've just changed my fiddle and it seemed to work fine using `typeof` as long as it's used in a ternary `if`.

Comment: insted you can use like this- typeof partnerId !== "undefined" ? self.renderViewContent("myText1", view, {
    myAttr1: myModel.get("attr").toJSON()
})  :  self.renderViewContent("myText2", view, {
    myAttr1: myModel.get("attr").toJSON()
})

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not pass any conditional logic in your code, but the result of some expression. This is very possible :)

Having said this: Is your intention to evaluate the expression (late) in the context of the called function (i.e. is partnerId defined there?)
In this case you could pass a function like:

```
self.renderViewContent(function(partnerId) { return typeof partnerId !== "undefined" ? "myText1" : "myText2"; }, view, {
myAttr1: myModel.get("attr").toJSON()
});
```